# KNIME mysql table update

Tags: mysql, knime

I am just now learning KNIME. I have successfuly set up a MySQL connector and connected a database reader to it. Then I did a database writer that basically aggregates data and pushes it to a new table.

My problem comes when I just need to do a simple update statement on my newly generated table.

I basically need to say update table1 set year = 2017 where ID < 2000;

I have looked and tried for hours but I cannot seem to figure out how to just run a simple update statement on a table from KNIME.

Please let me know if you need anymore information and as always thank you so much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (though not in a transaction):

- read the rows and with `Row Filter` select those with ID < 2000
- change the year column to 2017 with the `Constant Value Column`
- use the `Database Update` node with `SET` column `year` and `WHERE` columns all others (or just `id` if that is unique).